# PowerBI: Can imported data be updated by using (GET) /added, /updated and /deleted REST endpoints?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm doing an internship at a company which supply a software package that is a similair idea to SAP but much smaller and focussed on a different segment. The company wishes to implement support for BI tooling by providing a REST API. My current job is to find out whether the following scenario is possible: The API has three endpoints per data point (I.E. orders, invoices, etc): /added, /removed, /updated. This should allow any client to derive the current state of the data point without having to retrieve the entire dataset.

In theory this should be possible but I'm having a lot of trouble decyphering if PowerBI (or any other tools for that matter) could be implemented in some way to support this behaviour... PowerBI offers things like incremental refresh but I don't have a license to try out such a scenario and the documentation is too difficult for a complete PowerBI noob to understand enough to make any conclusions. Could someone help me by pointing me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot!
Stijn